# Powershell - Trouble with incrementing counter for label making script

Tags: powershell, printing

Edit: Thanks to Jason Boyd, he explained that `$i` and `$counter` are separate so even if `$i` gets incremented, `$counter` would not since it will always reference it at 0. I changed the code so `$i` was my starting value, then incremented `$counter` instead. Doing so got everything wot work properly.

I'm an extremely new person to Powershell (started 4 hours ago). I'm trying to make a small script that takes user input and outputs to a file then prints that file to a label printer. From current testing I got everything to work, except the incrementing counter. it never seems to go above 0 thus causing a infinite print loop. I want the increment becasue say if I have 10 pallets of product I want 10 labels that read "1 of 10" through "10 of 10" I've researched this for about and hour and tried a few suggestions and they don't seem to work. This is the script I have right now just with generic names(sorry for post format):

```
$i = 0
$counter = $global:i + 1


Write-Host "========== Print Comapny Labels =========="
Write-Host "Question will be on the left, type in answer and hit ENTER"

$location = Read-Host "Which location? (LOC1 or LOC2)"
$pro = Read-Host "What is the Pro#?"
$quote = Read-Host "What is the quote number?"
$pallet = Read-Host "How many pallets are there?"
$printer = Read-Host "What printer do you want?"

While ($counter -le $pallet)
{
    Set-Content -Path "C:\temp\Label.txt" -Value "^XA^MCY^XZ^XA^SZ2^MMT^MTT~JSN^LT0^MD0^MNY^PR5^PON^PMN^CI0^LRN
                                  ^FT300,1300^A0B,350,160^FDPRO #: $pro^FS
                                  ^FT480,1300^A0B,175,150^FD$location^FS
                                  ^FT480,900^A0B,175,100^FDQuote #: $quote^FS
                                  ^FT800,1300^A0B,350,225^FDPallet $counter of $pallet^FS
                                  ^PQ01~*QUANT,04~,0,~*COPIES,04~,N^MCY^XZ"

    Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Label.txt" | Out-Printer -Name "$printer"

    $global:i++
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You never increment `$counter`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the second line? logically $counter should be whatever $i is +1 so as long as $i increments $counter should as well.

Comment: No, it does not work that way.  `$i` is a value type (an integer in this case); value types are passed by value not by reference.  That means that `$counter = $global:i + 1` is not a reference to `$i` but a copy of the value of `$i` at that moment.  The two variables are completely independent of each other.  Incrementing `$i` has no effect on `$counter`.

Comment: That was it! I changed the scope to `$global:counter` just in case and changed the increment in the While statement to `$global:counter++` and now it only prints the max number of pallets entered. Now I have  some strange behavior on my hands. The label data seems to be coming through to the printer but all out of place. When I print the existing label left from the script, to the same printer, it prints perfect. I'll see if I can figure out what is causing this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem has to do with inconsistent use of the `global:` prefix.

You initialize `$i` as a local variable, but then use and increment it as `$global:i`.   Seems like the global never gets initialized.   I'd just drop the global: prefix everywhere unless you have a specific reason for using it.

Comment: I initially used `$i` instead of `$global:i`. It did not work before. Trying to find an answer on Google, a lot of people were saying it was a scope issue and suggested to use `$global:i`

I just tested the script again with `$i` all around and `$global:i` all around and further `$global:i` with `$global:counter` all around. All three variations ended with no increments and a infinite print loop.